# Como consumir dados Razor em um arquivo javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor

Sou novo por aqui, estou tentando consumir dados Razor dentro de um arquivo js. Pelo que entendi as duas linguagens não se comunicam por isso precisaria de uma alternativa que faça a intermediação, levando os dados do Razor para o javascript, mas não sei como aplicá-lo.

Meu script:

```
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
```

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart(dados) {

```
if (dados === undefined)
    dados = "**@Html.Raw(Model.GraficoColaboradores.JsonDados)**";

var obj = eval(dados);

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Unidades');
data.addColumn('number', 'Colaboradores');
data.addRows(obj);

var options = {
    chartArea: {
        'width': '80%',
        'height': '80%'
    },
    legend: { position: "none" },
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar o script na pagina cshtml dentro da tag `<script>`, aí você usa a tag `<text>` para o compilador entender que não é C#:

```
<script>
<text>
if (dados === undefined)
    dados = "**@Html.Raw(Model.GraficoColaboradores.JsonDados)**";

var obj = eval(dados);

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Unidades');
data.addColumn('number', 'Colaboradores');
data.addRows(obj);

var options = {
    chartArea: {
        'width': '80%',
        'height': '80%'
    },
    legend: { position: "none" },
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);

</text>
</script>
```

Só tome cuidado quando for comparar com `<` dentro da tag `<text>` o compilador vai  entender que está abrindo uma tag. Solução simples é inverter, por exemplo, se `a < b` vira `b > a`, nesse sentido.